# Plastic SCM Use questions

Tags: plasticscm

I had a couple question on using Plastic SCM that I could not find answers to elsewhere.

1) Can you link up a plastic Server to multiple databases? (Maybe 1 project for each database?)(I figure no) Also if we are planning on using this for multiple projects is it better to set permissions correctly and have a single plastic server, or have a separate plastic server for each project?

2) When you buy plastic for 15 users, am I breaching the license by making a second server of the same 15 users? or even a different 15 users?

3) Are there any poor effects of hosting the Plastic Server and DB on the same box? (Planning on using VM's for both)

4) When importing history for SVN, or any version control, do you need to have a clean database?

5) Is there a way to move only certain repositories to a new plastic server? ( I realize you can move the entire thing and delete the ones you don't want. Thats plan A)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go:

1) Server multiple databases: every repository in plastic is a different database. Is that what you mean? It is perfectly doable and the way to go in fact. You can use permissions to restrict access on different projects.

2) Licensing: each user needs a license. If you have 30 different users, then you need 30 licenses. You can use a server per user at no extra cost, of course, and a user as many computers as he wants, but each user needs a license :-)

3) Db server and Plastic server on the same host: it is the best option for super higher perf in fact, since you reduce latency.

4) Import: yes, normally you need an empty repository to import from another version control. Remember you can go from svn to git easily, then it is pretty obvious to plastic (gitsync or fast-import).

5) Move a repo to a different server: two ways of achieving this. a) move the database if you're an expert on the db. b) use plastic replica to clone the repo :P or the branches you want :-)

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: 1) Not exactly what I meant. Can you hook plastic up to a SQL DB and a mySQL and put certain repositories on each?